# GitLab (self-hosted) and GitKraken

Tags: gitlab, gitkraken

I'm struggling trying to connect GitKraken with a self-hosted GitLab, here is the problem:

I fill the host input and then I try to generate a personal token:

[image: Authentication-PersonalAccessToken]

But when I try to generate the personal access token the scope options doesn't appear:

[image: Gitlab personal access token creation]

When i try to connect with the provided token this message pops off:

[image: Invalid access token message]

Am I missing some kind of configuration?

Comment: What GK version are you using? There was a fix for a GitLab connection issue in version 3.5.1, see [Release Notes](https://support.gitkraken.com/release-notes/current).

Comment: @kowsky 3.5.1(64-bit) at that moment, now 3.6.0(64-bit), and still unable to connect.

Answer (score 0):

What GitKraken name as your "personal access token" is what GitLab name "private token".

To get it, you have to go to `User Settings > Account`

Comment: To authenticate, I used the host name and my private token, but for my host, I didn't use `http://`, I wrote directly `mygitlab.example.com`. I cannot see any other difference...